# Limit of $\frac{1}{x}\ln{\frac{\exp{x}-1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the limit of $\dfrac{1}{x}\ln{\frac{\exp{x}-1}{x}}$ at $+\infty$ using equivalence ($\widetilde { +\infty }$ Little o)?

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Comment: i have used my calculator and obtained $ 0.49.. $ with $ x=0.0001 $ so the limit must be $ 0.5 $ :D

Comment: @Jose That would be limit for $x\to 0^+$. (It is indeed equal to $1/2$.) The OP asks about limit for $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^x - 1 \sim e^x$$

$$\ln(\frac{e^x}{x}) =  x - \ln(x) \sim x $$

$$\frac{1}{x} \cdot x = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Noting that 
$$
\ln(e^x - 1) = \ln (e^x(1-e^{-x}))
$$
you get
$$
\ln\frac{e^x - 1}{x} = x  - \ln x + \ln(1-e^{-x})
$$
and 
$$
\frac{1}{x}\ln\frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1  - \underbrace{\frac{\ln x}{x}}_{o(1)}  + \underbrace{\frac{\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x}}_{o(1)} \sim 1
$$